# Struts2 JQuery Datepicker not working properly

Tags: java, struts2, datepicker, struts2-jquery

I am using a datepicker in form to send particular date and time to my action class. But When I submit my form the datepicker value received at action is

```
Wed Jan 29 00:00:00 IST 2014
```

means, the date is going correct but the time not. How can I solve the problem???

My Form :

```
<form theme="simple" action="saveDetailsRecBackupConf" method="post" name="viewConfiguration">
        <sj:datepicker theme="simple" id="addedon" name="addedon" timepicker="true" timepickerShowSecond="true" timepickerFormat="HH:mm:ss" ></sj:datepicker>           

        <input type="submit" value="SAVE" name="SUBMIT" id="save" />
</form>
```

Comment: How do you convert date objects?

Comment: convert to what??? @AleksandrM

Comment: What type is `addedon` property in your action?

Comment: addedon is of `java.util.Date` type @AleksandrM

Comment: @AnkitLamba What date format do you want to receive?

Comment: You need to convert from string to date. For some types S2 does it automatically. Read about type conversion: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/type-conversion.html.

Comment: I am sending the current time `Wed Jan 29 17:51:14 IST 2014` but, sent time is `00:00:00`

Comment: @AnkitLamba have you resolved this problem? i'm facing a similar trouble.

Comment: @maxx777 I had the same problem and removed my timestamps from the view layer.

Comment: @RomanC thanks for your reply. i have resolved this by taking it as a string a then parsing it into date. Now i want it to be validated. I will b thankfull if you provide help on [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194997/struts2-datepicker-with-time-validation)