# Datepicker with time validation in Struts 2

Tags: java, jquery, validation, struts2, datepicker

I'm using [Struts2 JQuery datepicker tag](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/DatePickerTag).

But I'm not able to validate it. In my `validation.xml` file, i am taking it as `date`, but it removes the time part. Any solution  to it? Should i use regex to validate my date time?

**JSP Form**

code is somewhat same as it was is in my  earlier question [Struts2 jquery datepicker passing 0 or null value to action class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836503/struts2-jquery-datepicker-passing-0-or-null-value-to-action-class)

**Action class:**

```
public Date getDateAndTimeOfOccurance() {
    return dateAndTimeOfOccurance;
}

public void setDateAndTimeOfOccurance(Date dateAndTimeOfOccurance) {
    System.out.println(dateAndTimeOfOccurance);
    this.dateAndTimeOfOccurance = dateAndTimeOfOccurance;
}

public String execute() throws Exception {
  .
  .
     
  ps.setTimestamp(13, new java.sql.Timestamp(getDateAndTimeOfOccurance().getTime())); 
  /*    i have modified my database because the time values in java.sql.Date have been depreciated  */
      
  .
  .
}
```

is there any existing solution for it? Should i use `regex` validator?

**UPDATE**

For experiment, I removed the validation part but the time received in the action is still `00:00:00`.

**UPDATE 2**
i found a way to solve this problem by recieving as mentioned in comments of of this question [Struts2 JQuery Datepicker not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429962/struts2-jquery-datepicker-not-working-properly). Also i have dropped validation.xml. Now i'm using annotation. Now the problem is how to validate it? should it be a `regex` or is there a struts validation way of validating a string as a date (like using `validate()` method, i'm not sure is it a good practice).

**UPDATED Code (with update 2)**

Action class

```
@RequiredStringValidator(message = "Please enter the date and time of occurance")
public String getDateAndTimeOfOccurance() {
    return dateAndTimeOfOccurance;
}

public void setDateAndTimeOfOccurance(String dateAndTimeOfOccurance) {
    this.dateAndTimeOfOccurance = dateAndTimeOfOccurance;
}

public void execute(){
  ....
  Date d = null;
  try {
      d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm", Locale.getDefault()).parse(getDateAndTimeOfOccurance());
  } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      addFieldError(dateAndTimeOfOccurance, "Please enter a valid date");
      return INPUT;
  }
  Timestamp t = new java.sql.Timestamp(d.getTime());
  ps.setTimestamp(13, t);

  ...
}
```

Comment: Have you read comments in that question?

Comment: @AleksandrM thanks. but i'm unable to validate it. should i use regex or date?

Comment: @maxx777 You already have asked the same question  http://stackoverflow.com/q/22836503/573032 . If you can update it so, that reflects the last state and formulate the question in some readable format, BTW what dislike you to have answers that you accept?

Comment: @RomanC i created a new post bcoz this time i ran into a different problem. earlier it was beacause of naming covention, this time it is because of the conversion issue by the plugin itself. if its unethical then i should remove one of the post. since i have resolved both the problems with the help of community, tou tell if i should delete the post or not. Thanks sir

Comment: @maxx777 If you have a new question, post only relevant code to it, don't duplicate it just make a reference to the previous question. So, edit the question and remove duplicate code, highlight the question and explain how it differs from the previous one. Then post an answer and accept it if you solved the problem.

Comment: @RomanC i have removed the duplicate code and have updated my new code. Kindly check the updated question. is it fine the way i'm doing or there exist a better way for this? and thanks for your advice. (y)

Answer (score 1):

Using `validate()` to validate your action code is a good practice. This type of validation is known as *programmatic* validation and is described in he Struts documentation under the [`validation` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation-interceptor.html). You can configure this interceptor to perform all kinds of validations which is the default setting. So, to use a programmatic validation by overriding a validate method vs *declarative* validation is a way you can do legally in your action. Of course you can do both types of validations via the same interceptor. The framework has support for many basic validators used by the core package, all of them are described under the section of [bundled validators](http://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation.html#bundled-validators). You can also extend the framework by providing your custom validators. The *classic* example of the [custom validator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20845823/573032) for validation of two fields.

Regardless of whichever type of validation you choose, you shouldn't do it in the action method (unless you have a reason to do it, and you know what are you doing) because you can use the framework features and the validation framework to separate the validation logic from the controller logic (assumed that business logic is performed on the service layer).

**The code you should fix:**

```
protected static SimpleDateFormat getDateFormat(){
  return new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm");
}

@Override
public void validate(){
  try {
    SimpleDateFormat df = getDateFormat();
    df.parse(dateAndTimeOfOccurance);
  } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    addFieldError(dateAndTimeOfOccurance, "Please enter a valid date"); 
  }
}


@Override
public void execute() throws Exception {
  SimpleDateFormat df = getDateFormat();
  Date d = df.parse(dateAndTimeOfOccurance);
  Timestamp t = new java.sql.Timestamp(d.getTime());
  ps.setTimestamp(13, t);
  ...
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

This code a bit clumsy because it needs to parse a string field twice (and as many times as needed if you want to get a `Date` value from the string field). Also, It used a fixed format pattern regardless of the context's locale.